# Can't pass a parameter through the URL using <c:url> tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jstl

I am using Spring MVC + Spring Security and I am trying to implement pagination.
To do that, I modified the link in my menu that is pointing to the page where I am going to use pagination.

When clicking the "List" link in my menu with the code below, I got an error 400 : The requested resource is not available.

```
<li>
  <a href="<c:url value="/list.htm" ><c:param name="page" value="1" /></c:url>">List
  </a>
</li>
```

When adding the parameter to the link, without using `<c:param>`, same thing, error 400:

```
<li><a href="<c:url value="/list.htm?page=1" />">List</a></li>
```

When simply using this, without passing any parameter, the link is working properly:

```
<li><a href="<c:url value="/list.htm" />">List</a></li>
```

Here is the related code in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployees(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("employees", this.employeeManager.getEmployees(page));
        return "list";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following request mapping which uses a wildcard.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list.htm*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployees(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("employees", this.employeeManager.getEmployees(page));
        return "list";
    }
```

You could also try without the wildcard but including .htm

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployees(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("employees", this.employeeManager.getEmployees(page));
        return "list";
    }
```

Comment: @Dukable, glad I could help.  You may want to see the update, you may not need the wildcard, the `.htm` portion may have did the trick

Comment: It also works when only adding .htm, without the wildcard, thank you again :)

Answer (score -1):

In Spring Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String funcName(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page){
return String;
}
```